# Foreach children() SimpleXML doesn't give me full structure

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So I have the following XML file where I'm only interested in the `<respcondition>` elements where there is only the `<or>` element in and not the `<and>` element.

I tried in PHP the following statement:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
foreach ($item->resprocessing->children() as $child) {
  if ((string) $child->getName() == 'respcondition') {
    if ((string) $child->respcondition->children()->getName() == 'conditionvar') {
      if ((string) $child->respcondition->conditionvar->children()->getName() == 'or') {
        $responseID = $child->respcondition->conditionvar->or->varequal->attributes()->respident;
        //some code
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

But I only come in the first IF, so I figured out that `children()` doesn't contain the entire XML from that element. Are there some alternatives I can use?

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<resprocessing>
  <outcomes>
    <decvar varname="SCORE" vartype="Decimal" defaultval="0" minvalue="0.0" maxvalue="1.0" cutvalue="1.0"/>
  </outcomes>
  <respcondition continue="Yes" title="Mastery">
    <conditionvar>
      <or>
        <varequal respident="1000006631" case="Yes"><![CDATA[Mars]]></varequal>
      </or>
    </conditionvar>
    <setvar varname="SCORE" action="Add">1.0</setvar>
  </respcondition>
  <respcondition continue="Yes" title="Mastery">
    <conditionvar>
      <or>
        <varequal respident="1000006678" case="Yes"><![CDATA[Jupiter]]></varequal>
      </or>
    </conditionvar>
    <setvar varname="SCORE" action="Add">1.0</setvar>
  </respcondition>  
  <respcondition title="Mastery" continue="Yes">
    <conditionvar>
      <and>
        <or>
          <varequal respident="1000006421" case="Yes"><![CDATA[planets]]></varequal>
        </or>
        <or>
          <varequal respident="1000006468" case="Yes"><![CDATA[sun]]></varequal>
        </or>
        <or>
          <varequal respident="1000006558" case="Yes"><![CDATA[Mercury]]></varequal>
        </or>
      </and>
    </conditionvar>
    <displayfeedback feedbacktype="Response" linkrefid="Mastery"/>
  </respcondition>
</resprocessing>
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at extracting it via xpath;

The following will return you all the respcondition nodes, having a conditionvar node, with only "or" childnodes in it. In your xml example, this will not return anything, which i believe you're aiming at.

```
$xmlDoc->xpath('/resprocessing/respcondition[conditionvar/or]');
```

Or, if you would like to extract the respcondition nodes, but now baring the "and" childnode in mind, use;

```
$xmlDoc->xpath('/resprocessing/respcondition[conditionvar/and/or]');
```

xpath is an easy and powerful way of navigating and extracting xml document, use it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SimpleXml::xpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to get those nodes directly:

```
/resprocessing/respcondition[descendant::or and not(descendant::and)]
```

Also have a look at this [XPath tutorial](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html).